What is this is the unpopulated SMD two-pad footprint reference "KR" intended for?
I have very little experience with PCB’s and their more exotic components.
I am attaching a photo of a microphone\speaker board from an icom hand mike.
I am unsure as to the part as it is marked KR which should mean reed
Relay, but there is no part there ;)
It look more like some sort of capacitor (formed by the two plates) which is effected by the flow\or no flow through the middle conductor.
I haven’t seen anything like this before.
Would love an explanation as to what it is


Thanks for the answers.
Should have known that the simplest answer would be the right answer ;)

Unrelated to your question, this is a botched solder job. Looks like they've been using wave soldering or something and it didn't end well. Also looks like they've been doing some mechanical cutting on a lot joints after soldering, which wouldn't be ok as per the IPC recommendations. If you are experiencing problems with this device, some extra flux and re-heating the joints will probably fix it. Try to remove excess solder at the same time. Wire connections are botched too and they might break in case of shock/vibration etc.

It’s a cheap clone. Would expect any better ;) the original ICOM board is probably nicer. I will try suggestion if I have problems

There are 2 zero ohm resistors (jumpers) on that board (oddly both are labeled R2).  RK appears to be a place for another one.
This is a typical approach to design reuse.  By populating, or not populating, the jumpers configure the board for different applications (probably for different radios in this case).
If I were to guess, I'd say that the missing jumper allows the SPKR- to be connected to ground for radios with a single-ended output (most commercial radios are differential BTL outputs).

If you compare the "0.00" text for "KR" with the "0.00" text next to the zero ohm resistor placed as "R2", it appears that it is a space for a zero ohm resistor (a.k.a. wire link).
"KR" might have been installed during the debugging stage of the PCB. If you can see any tiny indentations in its pads then maybe it is used for testing during production - the indentations would be due to probes.

You're overthinking this.
This is simply a place where no component has been placed – and judging by the untinned pads, intentionally.
